# XMLHttpRequest Error while fetching with Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, cors

I'm fetching a url with Axios in a React app & it's giving me this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://144.xxx.xxx.xxx:5051/a/b/c' from origin 'http://my-test-project.surge.sh' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This doesn't work on `localhost:3000` either. But I'm able to view the result of 'http://144.xxx.xxx.xxx:5051/a/b/c' when I open it in Chrome directly or when I curl it.

1. I don't control the server so is this something that has to be solved from the server of 'http://144.xxx.xxx.xxx:5051/a/b/c' by allowing my url for CORS (or all URLs), if so I have to contact the backend team.
2. Or is it an issue with something on my React app/Axios?